# dynamically add a property to an object in an array

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to add a property in an object inside an array, and I just cant make it work:

So I am passing an array to `Names.vue` which contains `['John', 'Jane']`, and I am trying to show some icons next to the name when the user hover over that name:
[A live example of the problem](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-cookies-hwy7z)

Names.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(name, index) in names" :key="index">
        <span @mouseenter="name.showIcons = true" @mouseleave="name.showIcons = false">{{ name }}</span>
        <span v-if="name.showIcons" style="margin-left:10px">icons</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    names: Array
  }
};
</script>
```

But this doesn't work? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively - you can use `this.$set`:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Names :names="names"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Names from "./components/Names";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Names
  },
  data() {
    return {
      names: [{ name: "John" }, { name: "Jane" }]
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(name, index) in names" :key="index">
        <span
          @mouseenter="setIconsState(index, true)"
          @mouseleave="setIconsState(index, false)"
        >{{ name.name }}</span>
        <span v-if="name.showIcons" style="margin-left:10px">icons</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    names: Array
  },
  methods: {
    setIconsState(index, isShow) {
      this.$set(this.names[index], `showIcons`, isShow);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, this works for my case. @MajedBadawi approach works as well but I prefer this for my case.